# SQL Server & Excel - Refresh on other users pc's

Tags: sql-server, excel, odbc

I'm using Excel 2010 to connect to a view in SQL Server and am displaying the data in an excel report. I want other users to be able to refresh this report but it doesn't allow them to. Does each user need access rights to the database?

Are there any options I can set in the data connections window to tell excel to use my access/login during a refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each user will need access to the specific database.  I would highly suggest against using your login as a global credential for security reasons.  You don't want to be giving the end user of a spreadsheet the same sort of development access that you have.  At my last company, we would either give permissions to the individual user or have the spreadsheet use a specific account set up for running reports and spreadsheets.

Comment: Thanks but how would I use my  credentials as a global login? The person who needs to refresh this spreadsheet doesn't even have a sql editor on his machine and our IT team doesn't want to give access to the database unless you are in a tech role.

Comment: Go to the excel spreadsheet, click the data tab -> From Other Sources -> SQL Server. You'll get to the Connect to a Database Server pop up window.  You can type in the server name and manually enter in credentials here.  I would suggest having your IT team set up an account that is specifically meant for these reports that can be used on all of them, that only has the minimum permissions to run the reports.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I can't login when I type my credentials. I can only connect when using windows authentication. Can I try something else?

Comment: I would suggest getting your IT to set up an account specifically for this purpose with the appropriate credentials that allows you to use a user name and password. Otherwise you're going to have to provide a business justification to your IT shop as to why these users need this report.  You could also set this spreadsheet up on an excel scheduler using a job.  A final suggestion, which would be a step back in my opinion, would be to use VBA to call an ODBC connection and allow them to hit the database that way.  I think the best solution is to allow the users access only to the one database.

Comment: Worst case scenario you can update the spreadsheet yourself whenever they need it and send it off to them until a more permanent solution is figured out.